# How do is pass dictionaries to url_for in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to pass an endpoint to `url_for` where the endpoint contains `name=value` parameters where the *name* is a variable.

Basically i have multiple templates which could be collapsed down to one template if I could pass parameter variable names. A solution could be to pass a dictionary, but there may be other ways. I could definitely do it by post-processing the html jinja generates before it gets rendered.

I have tried all the obvious tricks I can think of including nested `{{ }}`.

So at the end of my route code I have

```
# routes.py
...
@bp.route('/customer/add/prompt/<customer_id>',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def customer_add_prompt(customer_id):
    #code code code
    return render_template('customer_add.html',
        customer_id = customer_id)
```

Indeed I have *lots of routes* for different subjects (customer, product, invoice) that *all* end this way. So for each subject I need a jinja template that looks like this.

```
# customer_add.html
...   
<form action = "{{ url_for(customer_add, customer_id = customer_id) }}" method = "POST">       
    <-- html htlm htlm -->
</form>
```

When the user submits the form the endpoint for `customer_add` is followed and `customer_add` expects and is passed `customer_id = 1234` (or whatever the value is).

Here is the problem. I should be able to combine all the templates like so.

```
# subject_add.html
...   
<form action = "{{ url_for(subject_target, subject = subject_id) }}" method = "POST">       
    <-- html htlm htlm -->
</form>
```

Then render it like so.

```
# routes.py
...
@bp.route('/customer/add/<customer_id>',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def customer_add_prompt(customer_id):
    #code code code
    subject_target = 'customer_add.html'
    subject = 'customer_id'
    subject_id = customer_id
    return render_template(subject_target,
        subject = subject_id)
```

When I do this I get an error saying `Could not build url for endpoint 'customer_add' with values ['subject']. Did you forget to specify values ['entity_id']?`

Testing shows that `subject_target` and `subject_id` get substituted for fine. But `subject` is not substituted for because in the `url_for` syntax it is a parameter name and the endpoint is expecting a value for a variable named `customer_id` not `subject`.

I am hoping there is a way to say what the parameter name will be in jinja. Generalising I may want to pass a dictionary of parameters.

Ideally I could pass `d = {'subject': x, ...}` like this `url_for(subject_action, d)` and Jinja would regard this as equivalent to `url_for(subject_action, subject=1234, ...` when x=1234.

Comment: I suggest to dont have relevant data in url ,reccomend to send in post params

Comment: Okay rereading the question - are you trying to pass from your view to your template or the other way around?

Comment: Thanks, i have expanded the question to make it clearer. Because the endpoint in the url_for call is expecting a specific parameter name I am not sure is passing the parameters by "spilling" then into a dictionary will work?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build and endpoint for `customer_add`, but the function you have shown us is `customer_add_prompt`. This might be the source of your error as they should be the same.

Comment: Thanks, that is a typo. Checking and thinking about it there is no issue with a two-phase `add_customer_prompt` and `add_customer` approach rather one-phase `add_customer` approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can add arguments to `url_for()`. As per the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=url_for#flask.url_for):

> Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are
>   appended to the generated URL as query arguments

so you can do

```
<form action = "{{ url_for(action_target, 
                           subject_type=subject_id, 
                           2nd_variable=2nd_variable, 
                           etc...) }}" method = "POST">
```

But as wonka said you'd probably be better off sending data as `POST` params.

If I misunderstood and your trying to pass data from your `render_template` call in your view then you can do that too.

```
return render_template('template_name.html', 
                        data={
                            "action_type": "action",
                            "subject_type": subject_value
                        })
```

which you can then access in your template using `{{data["subject_type"]}}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be obvious. Instead of evaluating `url_for` in the template using jinja, evaluate it in the route and pass the result to jinja via `render_template`.